# bootstrap-table - in getAllSelections, can I only grab certain colums?

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table (https://bootstrap-table.com/).  I load lists of users from Active Directory via ajax and just after the data loads I want to grab two columns of data (cn,dn) from the rows displayed.  Some of these rows are already selected.   After the user selects or deselects certain rows, I will grab this new/changed data and compare it to the original data loaded.

I am currently getting the "original" data loaded using the

```
JSON.stringify($table.bootstrapTable('getAllSelections') method
```

but I extraneous data and I only want 2 columns (the cn and dn).  Is there a way to filter the 'getAllSelections' method?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want two fields from each array object and assuming you want distinguishedName and cn:

https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#methods/get-selections.html#view-source

I have tested this on my system and it returned the results I was expecting.

```
var results = $table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').map(function(elem, index) {
   return {
      cn: elem.cn,
      distinguishedName: elem.distinguishedName
   };
});
console.dir (results) 
var JSON = JSON.stringify(results)
console.dir (JSON)
```